# Where to put a command-line utility in an R package?

Tags: r, r-package

In [Hadley's R package docs](https://r-pkgs.org/package-structure-state.html#bundled-package), it shows a directory structure with "man", "R", "src", "tests", "vignettes", "inst" subdirectories.

Suppose I have a command-line utility written in R that I wish to distribute with the package.  Call it `foo.R`.  Where should I put that?  `inst/bin/foo.R`?

Comment: I think it goes into R and you document it with roxygen2 have you tried using usethis? Like `usethis::use_r("function_name")`

Comment: @Bruno I think the issue with putting command-line utilities in the "R" subdirectory is that package creation will try to run them, but they require command-line args, so it will fail.

Comment: Sure. I've also seen `inst/exec/foo.R`.  _Anything_ below `inst/` passes through as is, amd the directory will not be on the user's `$PATH` so you're the one calling it.  So you get to pick.